# How to do an 'and' statement in XSLT select?

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements

What is an example of a compound select statement using an `AND` operator, similar to an `if` statement where condition 1 = true and condition 2 = true?

Comment: can you give an example of the xslt you have so far and an xml fragment for input?

Comment: @Stephen: Do you want an example of the use of [`and`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans) operator?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and very simple example. :)

Comment: @Alejandro- I actually found one of your examples with 'and' op. TY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use a compound select statement....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<A>
    <B>
        <C>1</C>
        <D>2</D>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>1</C>
        <D>3</D>
     </B>
    <E>test</E>
</A>
```

and your current template match is for "E", **then try the below code to select only B where C = 1 and D = 3: for C and D read condition 1 = true and condition 2 = true**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="E">
        <xsl:value-of select="../B[C = 1][D = 3]"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="C"/>
    <xsl:template match="D"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Good Luck

Comment: Your answer could be misleading... This `*[.='text' and position()=2]` isn't the same as `*[.='text'][position()=2]`.

Comment: @Alejandro - updated my answer to reflect this issue, apologies. I was not intending to mislead anyone at all.

Comment: Actually A[B][C] is equivalent to A[B and C] provided (i) both B and C are boolean (not numeric) expressions, and (ii) C does not depend on position() or last().

Answer (score 4):

**Here is one of the simplest possible examples**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match=
    "num[. mod 2  = 0 and . mod 3 = 0]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on this XML document:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<num>06</num>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the AND operator:

```
<xsl:if test="a and b">
```

Comment: I thought the question was for a SELECT statement? Not an IF, but might have misunderstood. "What is an example of a compound select statement using an and operator"

Comment: You are correct.  Once I saw example code, I realized I was mistaken.  I'll leave this here for reference for other folks in the future.